# Failing to deploy portfolio app with heroku and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy a portfolio Rails6 app with heroku but when I run git push heroku main it says

Precompiling assets failed.
Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

I will share with you some screenshots of the terminal so that you can understand more about the problem. If you want you can see my code at https://github.com/andreamaf01/portfolio. I hope that you can help me, y'all have a good day.

[terminal-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n3IH.png)
[terminal-img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwEcH.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the log screenshots posted by you, there is issue with your "package-lock.json" file.